# How to include git submodules and their physical files in parent repository?

Tags: github, git-submodules, git-subtree, git

The story starts from a git repository. Let's call it pet-shop.
The pet-shop has 2 folders containing different projects.

```
--pet-shop          <== this is a repository
  --web             <== subfolder angular project
  --rest-api        <== subfolder python project
```

Due to within the same git repository, there is an issue that when developers commit changes to either **pet-shop/web** or **pet-shop/rest-api** the history logged to pet-shop. This makes no sense. Like as someone working within **web**, he/she doesn't need to know what's happend in **rest-api**.

Therefore, I was trying to split them out. I noticed git submodule feature.
After spending an hour on googling. It now ends up 3 git-repositories.

```
--pet-shop                            <==== this is a git repository
  --web @9se5082                      <==== refer to git repo pet-shop-web
  --rest-api @defs02d                 <==== refer to git repo pet-shop-rest-api


--pet-shop-web                        <==== this is a new git repository


--pet-shop-rest-api                   <==== this is another new git repository
```

This meets the initial requirement now. I could commit changes separately.

Logically they are connected; Physically they are stored respectively.

> My question now is, the way of doing this consumes 3 git repositories, could it be done by 1 repository?

Comment: I'm not sure it using sumobodules here worth it. Each time a developer changes something in submodule the parent should be updated. So they still need to operate with at least 2 of them. Unless there is performance issues, I'd keep going with singe repository.

Answer (score 2):

> My question now is, the way of doing this consumes 3 git repositories, could it be done by 1 repository?

literal answer is "yes". You could store several disconnected histories in one repository, you just need to name them as different branches. You still would have to have 3 repositories locally, but they could have same remote repository. But you would have to care twice as much to not merge them together or force push to wrong branch.

Comment: hey @max630 from what I understand here, it's feasible but you seem don't recommend to use branches to split them out in order to keep them in the same git repository. My concern is as expanding there might be plenty of git repositories. What's the best practice of coping this?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment, I do not think submodules are justified here. They are indeed a bit hard to manage. And having one repository is not going to help much, you'd have to operate with branches instead. The only sensible reason to do it is when you have some limitation of repositories, like private account at github.